# how much space should I allocate in this step?

Tags: system-installation

Yeah, finally I came to this step. It is really not easy.

[image]

I already create a brand new 40GB disk for ubuntu. Now installer ask me to allocate space again. what does it mean?

how about drag the line to left most?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your previous steps of course but the left part is Windows and the right part is Ubuntu. Normally it should show an icon but that could be a bug.

[image: Drag size]

Comment: thanks for sharing. I just create a new 40GB disk in windows 8, and restart to boot from USB. Finally got this.